# Center three divs inside one bigger, with same margin on left&right

Tags: html, css

Hi stack **overflow** community, im a beginner in css3/html5 and i'm struggling beacuse i dont know how to center three divs inside one bigger like in this image:

[image]

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: blue; 
  padding: 20px; 
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper:after{
  content:""; 
  display: block; 
  clear: both; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sez{
  width: 340px; 
  height: 240px; 
  float: left;
}

.sez1{
  background-color:green;
}

.sez2{
  background-color:red;
 }

.sez3{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sez sez1"></div>
  <div class="sez sez2"></div>
  <div class="sez sez3"></div>
</div>
```

---

This is the full code HTML:
pastebin.com/GT0a6ztG

This is the full code CSS:
pastebin.com/7dYuz3cC

Comment: Thanks all for the answers! I've resolved my problem.

I've never red about "Flexbox" and im going to read up all info that can i find :D

Thank you again guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways. This is one of them.

The answers of the others are good solutions, but they aren't working in your case.

You need to remove this piece of CSS:

```
.wrapper:after{
   content:""; display: block; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sez {
  width: 30%;
  height: 240px;
}

.sez1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.sez2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.sez3 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sez sez1"></div>
  <div class="sez sez2"></div>
  <div class="sez sez3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that with [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

The rule `justify-content: space-around;` will distribute the child elements evenly inside the parent element, `.wrapper`, and will apply equal spacing between and around them.

Depending on your browser-support needs you might need to add prefixes or different syntaxes.

Check [CSS-Tricks guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for excellent guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, cross browser. A `Parent` with `Margin: Auto` width `Fixed Width`

```
#sez {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/1ej42fxk/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `:last-of-type`:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.column {
  background-color: #000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 32%;
}

.column:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="column">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```